# python: Navigating a 4-D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am working with a 4-D array input to a CNN network. The input array has the following shape

```
print('X_train shape: ', X_train.shape)
X_train shape:  (47204, 1, 100, 4)
```

**Data description:**

The input data consists of a `47204` instances (fixed-length segments as far CNN requirement). Each instance `(1, 100, 4)` i.e. `1` segment contains `100-GPS points`, and for each point, `4-`corresponding point kinematics `(max_speed, avg_speed, max_acc, avg_acc)` are stored, thus the `(1, 100, 4)`. Labels are stored in a separate `y_train` array of shape `(47204,)` for 5 classes `[0..4]`.

```
print(y_train)
[3 3 0 ... 2 3 4]
```

To get a better sense of my `X_train` array, I show the first 3 elements below:

```
print(X_train[1:3])
[
 [[[ 3.82280987e+00 2.16802350e-01  7.49917451e-02  3.44416369e-04]
   [ 3.38707371e+00 2.02210055e-01  1.61751110e-03  1.93745950e-03]
   [ 2.49202215e+00 1.60605262e-01  8.43561351e-03  2.40057917e-03]
   ...
   [ 2.00022316e+00 2.70020923e-01  5.40441673e-02  3.57212151e-03]
   [ 3.25199744e-01 9.06990382e-02  1.46808316e-02  1.65841315e-03]
   [2.96587589e-01  0.00000000e+00  6.13293351e-04 4.16518187e-03]]]

 [[[ 1.07209176e+00 7.27038312e-02 6.62777026e-03  2.04611951e-04]
   [ 1.06194285e+00 5.05005456e-02 4.05676569e-03  3.72293433e-04]
   [ 1.02849748e+00 2.12558178e-02 2.95477005e-03  5.56584054e-04]
   ...
   [ 4.51962909e-03 5.63125736e-04 5.98474074e-04  1.63036715e-05]
   [ 2.83026181e-03 2.35855075e-03  1.25789358e-03 2.15331510e-06]
   [8.49078543e-03  2.16840434e-19 9.43423077e-04 1.29198906e-05]]]

 [[[ 7.51127665e+00 3.14033478e-01  6.85170617e-02  7.73415075e-04]
   [ 7.42307262e+00 1.33868251e-01  4.10564823e-02  1.16131460e-03]
   [ 7.35818066e+00  1.23886976e-02  3.02312582e-02  1.28312101e-03]
   ...
   [ 7.40826167e+00 1.19388656e-01 4.00874715e-02  2.04909489e-04]
   [ 7.23779176e+00 1.33269965e-01  1.20430502e-02  1.58195900e-04]
   [ 7.11697001e+00 4.68002105e-02  5.42478400e-02  3.58101318e-05]]]
]
```

**Task:**

I am required to create a machine learning model (e.g. random forest) using the 4 kinematics `(max_speed, avg_speed, max_acc, avg_acc)` as features. This requires navigating each instance and getting these features for the 100-points in the instance.

Clearly, the number of samples will then be `4720400` (i.e. `47204 x 100`), so would also match each value to the corresponding label of its instances, i.e. `y_train` will then be `(4720400,)`.

The expected input would then be like:

```
      max_speed     avg_speed         max_acc       avg_acc   class
0 3.82280987e+00 2.16802350e-01  7.49917451e-02  3.44416369e-04 3
1 3.38707371e+00 2.02210055e-01  1.61751110e-03  1.93745950e-03 3
2 2.49202215e+00 1.60605262e-01  8.43561351e-03  2.40057917e-03 3
...
```

I have being thinking about how to do this all through the week, all ideas evaporated. How do I do this, please?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need 100 ordered copies of every element in `y_train`. How about using NumPy's [repeat](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy.repeat) function?  

Another possibility could be mapping using the integer division `index // 100`, which effectively repeats itself 100 times for each index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reshape your `X_train` array from `(47204, 1, 100, 4)` to `(4720400, 4)` simply with:

```py
X_train_reshaped = X_train.reshape(4720400, 4)
```

It preserves the data order and the total number of elements will be the same.

Similarly, you can expand `y_train` array using `repeat` command:

```py
Y_train_reshaped = numpy.repeat(Y_train, 100)
```

Note the `100` for `repeat` command. Since you had one label for 100 data points, we will expand these items 100 times. This command will preserve data order too so all instances will have the same original label.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much for this answer. Precise and to the point.